# Aryl halides by Hunsdiecker reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I wanted to know wether we can prepare aryl halides by Hundiecker reaction or not. if so then what is its mechanism i know the mechanism for alkyl halides. please refer these links and please try to explain with reason.

http://www.organic-chemistry.org/abstracts/literature/918.shtm

http://www.organic-chemistry.org/abstracts/literature/449.shtm

Answer (score 4):

There might be more recent publications, but an old review by Robert G. Johnson and Robert K. Ingham, [Chem. Rev., **1956**, *56*, 219-269](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/cr50008a002), gives some directions.

Based on early attempts with benzoic acid that date back to the time around 1840, is was long believed that the silver salts of aromatic carboxylic acids do not undergo a Hunsdiecker reaction at all. The authors write:

> In no case was bromobenzene obtained as a result of the
>   action of bromine on silver benzoate. The product of Peligot and Bunge was a monobromobenzoic acid; apparently Kekule’s experiment was completely unsuccessful.

However, it later turned out that the inital verdict wasn't quite true.

Benzoic acids bearing electron-withdrawing substituents, such as $\ce{Cl}$ or $\ce{NO2}$ can be converted to their corresponding bromoarenes in a Hunsdiecker reaction. The authors of the review denote:

> Thus, the three isomeric nitrobenzoic acids (as silver salts) were
>   converted to the corresponding bromides in excellent yields (ortho, 95 per cent; meta, 89 per cent; para, 79 per cent). The yields from the chlorobenzoic acids were less satisfactory, but sufficiently high to indicate the efficacy of the chloro group.

Comment: Sir substituents like NO2 would work in case of carbanionic mechanism but how would this stabilise the intermediate in case of free radical mechanism

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent paper<sup>1</sup> which discussed the various ways of decarboxylative halogenation. In the section "2.1. The Hunsdiecker–Borodin Reaction", you will find tons of details including aryl halide synthesis with their yields:

[image]

The paper cited two sources for the reaction scheme<sup>2,3</sup>.

But the problem with these type of reactions is you end up contaminating your end products with chlorinated and mixed halide side products or esters if you mess up the stoichiometry.For e.g. Bromodecarboxylation of Silver Benzoate:

[image]

In some case, the aromatic halide end product is volatile e.g. Bromobenzene

**Notes and References**

1. Decarboxylative Halogenation of Organic Compounds by Andrii Varenikov, Evgeny Shapiro, and Mark Gandelman, Chemical Reviews **2021** 121 (1), 412-484
   DOI: [10.1021/acs.chemrev.0c00813](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemrev.0c00813)
2. Bockemüller, W.; Hoffmann, F. W. Über Carbonsäure-Hypohalogenite. Liebigs Ann. **1935**, 519, 165– 192,  DOI: 10.1002/jlac.19355190115
3. > Bromobenzene is volatile in vacuo at 100°C", but it was isolated contaminated with less than 10% of carbon tetrachloride. The low yield of benzyl bromide may be due to its volatility in vacuo at 100".
   >
   > Oldham, J. W. H. 22. A Study of the Action of Bromine on the Silver Salts of Organic Acids. J. Chem. Soc. **1950**, 100– 108,  DOI: 10.1039/jr9500000100 ([PDF](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1950/jr/jr9500000100?casa_token=lwRrVckuaPAAAAAA:I7xn6Jsxk4_nCHBj_YC729RYMCLRKYxipKNBBabxSsYy5f8tSvQunrFzCBLmX4ScnSgnm70v7zWZ0ws))
4. > When the silver of picolinic acid reacts with bromine in hot nitrobenzene, the expected bromopyridine is formed along with 2,2'-dipyridine
   >
   > *Reaction Mechanisms in Organic Chemistry* by Metin Balcı, **2021**